# TextField size issue on iPad?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, autolayout

I want my app to run on every device fine.I have text field on the screen.I am giving constraints to text field as follows:

- Aspect ratio to self
- Aspect ratio to parent view

I this case my text field will scale according to screen size.Now issue is when i use this method then all my textfields look too big on iPad.I have seen facebook app on which TextFileds don't look too big.I look decent so please tell me what method should i use for this purpose.I know i can use `size classes` but i don't want to use size classes in my project.

Solution i want if a textField is on iPhone 4s is 20px then on iPad it should be 24px with out using aspect ratio & size classes concept.

Comment: Do you want to use autolayout proportional constraints? Because it is possible through proportional constraints.

Comment: you should not give aspect size constraints. Give leading and trailing and top and bottom constraints

Comment: I have used aspect ratio concept but that make text filed look too big Because text fileds are scaled according to screen size.@Irfan

Comment: are you designing the layout on inferred size or freeform size ? or fixed size for iphone 5 ?

Comment: I am taking iPhone 5(4 inch) as base.Then i scale view accrdingly.

Answer (score 1):

Without Size classes You can achieve this using the following constraints. I have tested it on only one textfield and it is in center of screen. So overall constraints on this textfield is as follow:

1. Align center X to SuperView
2. Align center Y to SuperView
3. Width >= 168
4. Trailing Space to Superview Equals 270(approx) (priority = 999)
5. Leading space to Superview Equals 270(approx) (Priority = 999)
6. Height Equals : 30

What happen here is that On ipad 270 leading and trailing will be satisfied while on iphone having less width so both of these constraints shrink and width >= 68 constraints come in action. The result is show in pictures
IPHONE [image]
IPAD [image]

Comment: How do i decide the leading & trailing space? What is priority here?@Irfan

Comment: 1. Leading and Trailing depend on your situation. Increasing leading and trailing will make textfield smaller on ipad. 2. When you select a constraint or double click a constraint you can see priority option.

Comment: Less priority means when both leading and trailing constraints will fail on iphone then due less priority width constraint will come in action

Comment: So the width of 168 will be taken for all iPhone because it also fails to satisfy the width constraint?

Comment: Try playing with the leading and trailing values and you will achieve what you want. Without size classes and aspect ratio this is a great way. Constraints are not proportional but size is different on different devices. I have to go. Thanks

Comment: But i am saying with your example width of all iPhone devices will be 168 as it can't be satisfied for the iPhone screen.